# blank=False,null=False not working in models code Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.3

```
class Url(models.Model):
    url=models.URLField(verify_exists=True,max_length=200,blank=False,null=False)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    count=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isspam=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This is my models code....and when i make an object with no arguments..the object is created and is saved to the DB even after writing `blank=False,null=False` and the URL is also not checked for existence.If i supply it a dead link, it works but it shouldn't!

What is the problem with my code?

**Related Query**: Now that in django 1.4, verify_exists has been deprecated...how can i check for validation in 1.4?

Comment: Have you re-created the DB after the change?

Comment: @Rohan Yeah but the problem persists!

Comment: If you are editing an existing model and you run sync_db, it won't update the table.  Use `south` or similar to allow migrations.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115238/django-model-sync-table

Comment: Can you post `python manage.py sqlall <your_app>` and check these fields are not null?

Comment: @Rohan : don't worry about it..i did it...btw i got the hints on how to do this by sqlall and dir(Url)....sometimes i forget about dir but it's a lifesaver.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As you've seen, django does not validate model on save() by default, but your database should've thrown an error when inserting NULL value, I would check the schema to be sure.
2. Use [URLValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/validators/#urlvalidator)

Answer (score 0):

So i got it working by modifying my 'url' to  `url=models.URLField(verify_exists=True,max_length=200,default=None,blank=False,unique=True)`
 and validating it by object.clean_fields().

If you don't use valid values or empty values it throws errors like this

```
ValidationError: {'url': [u'This URL appears to be a broken link.'] }

ValidationError: {'url': [u'This field cannot be blank.'] }
```