# how to restore dropped table with django-south?

Tags: python, database, django, django-south, django-syncdb

I wanted to clear out a table in my DB, so I dropped the table. Normally I would do `manage.py syncdb` to re-create it. However, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590944/currently-using-django-evolution-is-south-better-and-worth-switching) says not to use `syncdb` anymore. So, what do I do instead?

Answer (score 42):

It's a pretty late response but for people who will run into the same issue (like I did).

Normally to drop the db_tables for the app that is managed by south you should use:

```
python manage.py migrate appname zero
```

But if you dropped them manually in the db let south know about it

```
python manage.py migrate appname zero --fake
```

And of course to recreate the tables

```
python manage.py migrate appname
```

Comment: I had the same problems as @EliAlbert (only one model dropped).  I was able to recover with [the steps in my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17374887/785400).

Comment: Just for clarification: *This only works if you dropped every table* . With *every* is meant *every table that corresponds to a model of the specified app*.

Answer (score 27):

Had the identical problem. Not sure this works in all circumstances, but here's what I did:

1. comment out "south" from INSTALLED_APPS
2. run manage.py syncdb
3. uncomment "south" in INSTALLED_APPS
4. run manage.py migrate

Voila!

Your mileage may vary....

Comment: you'll need to rename the migrations folder too whilst performing this, I just prefix with an underscore. do this between step 1 and 2 above, then rename back to 'migrations' before step 4

Answer (score 2):

Hmm [this exchange](http://groups.google.com/group/south-users/browse_thread/thread/40d993d1971d5089) covers my very question:

> If you modify the database by hand, South won't notice - its only way of 
>   keeping track of what version the database is is the 
>   south_migrationhistory table, so if you fiddle behind its back, it's 
>   your responsibility to fix it.

What I ended up doing was commenting out the model that I dropped in question, doing a `schemamigration`, creating an empty no-column table of the one I dropped (so South has something to drop), `migrate`ing, then un-commenting the model, `schemamigration` and `migrate`ing again. A bit more annoying than just dropping the table and `syncdb` but ah well.

Comment: Is it possible to create no-column table in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your migrations are applied:
`python manage.py migrate`

Tell Django to create the tables as they are in your models: `python manage.py syncdb`

Tell South that everything is where it should be: `python manage.py migrate appname --fake`

This assumes that nothing has changed in **any of your models** since you created your last migration.

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is old, but I just ran into this issue and thought I'd post my solution in case this helps anyone.

1. Go into your `models.py` folder where the database is.
2. Cut the entire class out of the `models.py` file.
3. Run ./manage.py schemamigration `appname` --auto (this will create another migration where `South` will recognize to delete this table). You may need to recreate a blank table in you database so `South` sees it.
4. Run the `migration` and the table should drop from your database.
5. Re-paste in your table class back to where it was in your `models.py` file.
6. Run a ./manage.py schemamigration `appname` --auto. South should pick up the table and allow you to migrate
7. Run ./manage.py migrate `appname` and South should re-add the table back into your databasse... with the columns and such again, but without the data, obviously. :)

Comment: Hah nice, this is exactly what my answer says but in a step-by-step layout.

Comment: Oh nice! Sorry, I didn't see you answer. Glad we both came to the same resolution, at least. :)