# Migrate django 1.11

Tags: python, django-models, model

Why when I try to migrate my model for every some Model that I add, though some error, like:

I don't wanna delete and create another database. I just wanna change the existing database and If I have some data in my data base?

```
(1060, "Duplicate column name ...)
(1054, "Unknown column 'vacina_agentmodel.phone' in 'field list'")
(1054, "Unknown column 'created' in 'vacina_vaccinemodel'")
```

Initial Migrate

```py
dependencies = [
    ('vacina', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='PatientModel',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ('complete_name', models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nome completo')),
            ('birthday', models.DateField(verbose_name='Data de nascimento')),
            ('email', models.EmailField(default='', max_length=200, verbose_name='Email')),
            ('phone', models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Número de telefone')),
            ('address', models.CharField(default='', max_length=200, verbose_name='Endereço')),
            ('house_number', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, verbose_name='Número da casa/apartamento')),
            ('country', models.CharField(default='', max_length=100, verbose_name='Pais')),
            ('province', models.CharField(default='', max_length=100, verbose_name='Estado')),
            ('zip_code', models.IntegerField(verbose_name='CEP')),
            ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ('last_modification', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
        ],
        options={
            'ordering': ('created_at',),
        },
    ),
]
```

///////////////////////

```py
dependencies = [
    ('vacina', '0008_auto_20170802_0507'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterModelOptions(
        name='agentmodel',
        options={'ordering': ('created_at',)},
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='agentmodel',
        name='country',
        field=models.CharField(default='', max_length=100, verbose_name='Pais'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='agentmodel',
        name='created_at',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='agentmodel',
        name='house_number',
        field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, verbose_name='Número da casa/apartamento'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='agentmodel',
        name='last_modification',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='agentmodel',
        name='phone',
        field=models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='Número de telefone'),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='agentmodel',
        name='province',
        field=models.CharField(default='', max_length=100, verbose_name='Estado'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='agentmodel',
        name='zip_code',
        field=models.IntegerField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='CEP'),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='agentmodel',
        name='email',
        field=models.EmailField(default='', max_length=200, verbose_name='Email'),
    ),
]
```

And my `models.py` file content :

```py
class PatientModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    complete_name = models.CharField(_('Nome completo'), max_length=100, blank=False)
    birthday = models.DateField(_('Data de nascimento'), blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(_('Número de telefone'), blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(_('Endereço'), max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
    house_number = models.CharField(_('Número da casa/apartamento'), max_length=10, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(_('Pais'), max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    province = models.CharField(_('Estado'), max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(_('CEP'), blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    last_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

class Meta: 
    ordering = ('created_at',)

def __meta__(self):
    return self.complete_name


class AgentModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    complete_name = models.CharField(_('Nome completo'), max_length=100, blank=False)
    birthday = models.DateField(_('Data de nascimento'), blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(_('Número de telefone'), blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(_('Endereço'), max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
    house_number = models.CharField(_('Número da casa/apartamento'), max_length=10, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(_('Pais'), max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    province = models.CharField(_('Estado'), max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(_('CEP'), blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    last_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

class Meta: 
    ordering = ('created_at',)

def __meta__(self):
    return self.complete_name


class VaccineModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    vaccine_name = models.CharField(_('Nome da vacina'), max_length=255, blank=False)
    against_indicative = models.TextField(_('Contra indicativo'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    avoided_diseases = models.TextField(_('Doenças evitadas'), max_length=200, blank=False)
    age = models.CharField(_('Idade'), max_length=255, blank=False)
    comments = models.TextField(_('Comentário adicional'), max_length=200, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    last_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('vaccine_name',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.vaccine_name
```

Comment: what are your `models.py` and which db are you using?

Comment: Can you share your models.py file

Comment: I'll comment my models.,py below

Comment: Take a look a my models.py below

Comment: Hello, I added the content of the `models.py` file to your question, for better clarity. Could you consider removing your answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Hey in your app folder there would be a folder named migrations try deleting all the files in format 001_initial.py and then run makemigrations command from command prompt, that allows you to edit models without deleting the whole database.

Edit: Hey follow this link: [Currently using Django "Evolution", is "South" better and worth switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590944/currently-using-django-evolution-is-south-better-and-worth-switching) try using south maybe this is the answer to your problem for handling changes once the database has been set

Comment: but that's temporary solution if models will be modified again it will again generate same error

Comment: yes, and the documentation say that's not a good practice, 'cause we need these migrations to do some rollback or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

My models.py

```
class PatientModel(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
complete_name = models.CharField(_('Nome completo'), max_length=100, blank=False)
birthday = models.DateField(_('Data de nascimento'), blank=False, null=False)
email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
phone = models.IntegerField(_('Número de telefone'), blank=True)
address = models.CharField(_('Endereço'), max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
house_number = models.CharField(_('Número da casa/apartamento'), max_length=10, blank=True)
country = models.CharField(_('Pais'), max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
province = models.CharField(_('Estado'), max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
zip_code = models.IntegerField(_('CEP'), blank=False)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
last_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

class Meta: 
    ordering = ('created_at',)

def __meta__(self):
    return self.complete_name


class AgentModel(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
complete_name = models.CharField(_('Nome completo'), max_length=100, blank=False)
birthday = models.DateField(_('Data de nascimento'), blank=False, null=False)
email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
phone = models.IntegerField(_('Número de telefone'), blank=True)
address = models.CharField(_('Endereço'), max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
house_number = models.CharField(_('Número da casa/apartamento'), max_length=10, blank=True)
country = models.CharField(_('Pais'), max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
province = models.CharField(_('Estado'), max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
zip_code = models.IntegerField(_('CEP'), blank=False)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
last_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

class Meta: 
    ordering = ('created_at',)

def __meta__(self):
    return self.complete_name


class VaccineModel(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
vaccine_name = models.CharField(_('Nome da vacina'), max_length=255, blank=False)
against_indicative = models.TextField(_('Contra indicativo'), max_length=500, blank=True)
avoided_diseases = models.TextField(_('Doenças evitadas'), max_length=200, blank=False)
age = models.CharField(_('Idade'), max_length=255, blank=False)
comments = models.TextField(_('Comentário adicional'), max_length=200, blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
last_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('vaccine_name',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.vaccine_name
```